# Change <ul> class on one specific menu?

Tags: routes

I'd like to change the  class from "menu" on one specific menu I have showing up as a block on about 3 pages in a Drupal 7 site. I've been researching but can't seem to figure out the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: If it's only for 3 pages, I believe fastest/easiest way to do this is through JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [theme_menu_tree()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7) hook in your theme's template.php file.
Or with a more specific version of `theme_mene_tree()` hook like `MYTHEME_menu_tree__MYMENU()`.

```
function MYTHEME_menu_tree__MYMENU(&$variables) {
    return '<ul class="nav newclass">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

See more here https://gist.github.com/gagarine/3201854

**UPDATE:**

if menu machine name have hyphne like main-menu then change hyphen to underscore, like `MYTHEME_menu_tree__main_menu()`

Comment: Would the MYMENU part just be the machine name of the menu?

Comment: Yes MYMENU part is just machine name of the menu. I tried with "management" menu like MYTHEME_menu_tree__management it worked.  But this will not work if menu machine name have hyphen like main-menu or user-menu.

Comment: UPDATE: if menu machine name have hyphne like main-menu then change hyphen to underscore, like MYTHEME_menu_tree__main_menu().

Answer (score 0):

If you need add class to your primary or secondary tabs you need change theme callback of `theme_menu_local_tasks()`. Use `hook_registry_alter()` to change callback. If you need change menu links, drupal has `theme_links()` which has `$variables['attributes']` where you can set class for ul. For this solution you need create function `mymodule_preprocess_links()` and set `$variables['attributes'] = array('class' => array('my-class'))`.

P.S. look at `theme_links()` or`theme_menu_local_tasks()` function to implement some solution.